# Upgrade to 2.1 breaks existing .net core EF logic

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have 2 objects with a FK relationship between them.  All of this logic worked fine when i was using .net core 2, but broke when i upgraded to 2.1

```
public class Parent
{
     [Key()]
     public Guid ParentGUID {get;set;}
     public string SomeValue {get;set;}
     [ForeignKey("ReferenceTypeGUID")]
     public ReferenceType ReferenceTypeObject {get;set;}
}
public class ReferenceType
{
     [Key()]
     public Guid ReferenceTypeGUID{get;set;}
     public string SomeOtherValue {get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Parent> ParentGU { get; set; }
}
```

and then in my dbcontext i have

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ReferenceType>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ReferenceTypeGUID);

                entity.HasMany(c => c.ParentGU)
                    .WithOne(e => e.ReferenceTypeObject)
                    .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentGUID)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
});
```

Now in my original code, i didn't have the HasForeignKey line, and i got the following error:

**cannot target the primary key because it is not compatible**

adding that line fixed that issue, but now i'm getting

**Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier**

for some reason, EF is assuming that the database type should be int instead of uniqueidentifier, even though the object is declared as a GUID.  how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please fix the sample (it's not compiling). Also apparently PK `ParentGUID` cannot be used as FK for many-to-one relationship, so keep the original code and the original problem with upgrading.

Comment: I assume by net core 2.1 you mean Entity Framework Core 2.1. Cannot reproduce with the provided code (even if I remove the apparently wrong `.HasForeignKey` line). Try reproducing it in a clean project and let us know, or check the code not shown here for something else that is causing it.

Comment: See https://github.com/vishnu4/EFCore21Test .  just run an add-migration, and you'll see the error : The relationship from 'Parent.ReferenceTypeObject' to 'ReferenceType.ParentGU' with foreign key properties {'ReferenceTypeGUID' : Nullable<int>} cannot target the primary key {'ReferenceTypeGUID' : Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

Comment: Thanks, reproduced!

Comment: You don't have a property in `Parent` that contains the foreign key reference.  Your parent class should have a property `public Guid ReferenceTypeGUID { get; set; }`.  I think you'll find the `[ForeignKey]` attribute expects to find the declared property name in the same class.

Comment: there is a referencetype object that fills that role actually, you don't need the actual GUID.  and like i say originally, this worked fine as written in 2.0, it was only the upgrade to 2.1 that caused an issue.  See the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like EF Core 2.1 has introduced a bug when you define a shadow FK property via `ForeignKey` annotation (frankly I didn't know this is supported at all). It incorrectly assumes `int` or `int?` type for that shadow property rather than considering the referenced PK property type.

You might fill an issue in their issue tracker if you wish. But I won't recommend using `ForeignKey` attribute for that purpose (or data annotations for relationships at all).

You can fix it by adding the following to the `Parent` entity fluent configuration:

```
entity.Property<Guid?>("ReferenceTypeGUID");
```

but this makes sense if you want to configure let say a different database column name for the shadow property.

A better (IMO) way is to **remove** the `ForeignKey` attribute and simply use the `HasForeignKey` overload with `string foreignKeyPropertyNames` parameter:

```
entity.HasMany(c => c.ParentGU)
    .WithOne(e => e.ReferenceTypeObject)
    .HasForeignKey("ReferenceTypeGUID") // <--
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

Comment: that did it for me, thank you.  Yeah, for some reason adding the ForeignKey attribute in the business object feels cleaner to me.  i like to add as much to the business object as i can and keep my OnModelCreating lean if possible, but thank you for helping me get it to work!